# django 1.9 serve media files in production

Tags: django

i currently switched to django 1.9 (from 1.8.4) and my media files stoped

to be served.. i.e. every file that is uploaded by a user isn't served in the

templates - the images are not shown and the downloaded files can't be download..

what might be the problem?

settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))   
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,   

document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

template:

```
<img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" height="30%" width="25%">
```

Comment: Why have you posted your URLs, since you should know that Django does not (and never has) served static files itself in production? Rather you should post your webserver configuration.

Comment: it also doesn't work in the development.. and it use to work in production too..

Answer (score 0):

this works for me (django 1.9.1)

in settings:

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

in urls:

```
    if settings.DEBUG:
        from django.conf.urls.static import static
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```